# CustomValidator is set to false but still the form is getting submitted

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Consider:

```
<telerik:RadTextBox TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="15" Wrap="True" ID="txtBody" runat="server" Width="95%" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="MenuLabelVal" runat="server" CssClass="Error" Text="*" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Maximum of 2000 characters allowed." ControlToValidate="txtBody" EnableClientScript1="true"  />
```

Code behind:

```
Protected Sub MenuLabelVal_ServerValidate(source As Object, args As ServerValidateEventArgs) Handles MenuLabelVal.ServerValidate
    If args.Value.Length > 2000 Then
        args.IsValid = False
    End If
End Sub
```

On submit button the click, the form is showing an error message, but still the form is getting submitted.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally in ASP.NET, we add a *Validation Group* for our Textbox validator and the same Validation Group for our Button so that when we click <kbd>Submit</kbd> it verifies the validation group errors.

Here is my code:

```
SortOrder: <font color="red">*</font>
           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
               runat="server"
               ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"
               ControlToValidate="txtsrtordr"
               ErrorMessage="Enter SortOrder"
               ValidationGroup="grp1">
           </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           <asp:TextBox
               runat="server"
               placeholder="Enter
               Sortorder"
               ID="txtsrtordr"
               MaxLength="8"
               onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" Width="100%">
           </asp:TextBox>
```

Button Click:

```
<asp:Button
    runat="server"
    ID="btnadd"
    Width="20%"
    Text="Add"
    CssClass="btn btn-info form-control"
    OnClick="btnadd_Click" 
    ValidationGroup="grp1"/>
```